# RaspberryPi Compute Module 4 bootloader EEPROM update issue

Tags: pi-4, bootloader, compute-module, pi4-eeprom

One day I got a new CM4 Lite module and the official IO board. I wanted to try a NVME disk as a boot device but I found that original EEPROM didn't have this option enabled (BOOT_ORDER didn't have 6 in it).

I downloaded usbboot source from github, I built it as described and I tried to run "rpiboot -d recovery" with a modified bootloader.
After EEPROM was successfully updated, my CM4 stopped booting from any source other than USB.

Its RED led always lit and GREEN led flashes only once after power is attached and then goes OFF. Nothing happens after that. It seems like EEPROM bootloader isn't working anymore.
Any subsequent recoveries worked well and EEPROM was updated successfully (I monitored the process via UART) but didn't give any result.

Any ideas what I can do now ? Thank you.

Comment: So, it doesn't even boot from the SD card?

Comment: No. I have another CM4 (with 16GB flash) and it works. The way how CM4 Lite behaves is similar to CM4 16GB with J2(1-2)  jumper short: both CM don't boot from flash(or SD) and green LED flashes once very shortly. After that both CMs can boot via rpiboot. But J2(1-2) jumper isn't fitted on CM4 Lite.

Comment: It seems like CM4 lite just skips any other boot source and goes directly to USB boot. As far as I know, it should load bootcode from EEPROM with no J2(1-2) short and green LED should reflect  this activity.

Comment: `should load bootcode from EEPROM` it does, and that bootcode boots from SD, USB, network or NVMe - in the order defined by `BOOT_ORDER` - what boot order have you defined when you did the recovery? - and ... have you tried booting with an SD card? .... `with a modified bootloader` you probably broke something

Comment: BOOT_ORDER=0xf25641

Comment: Yes, I have tried SD card with OS prepared by rpi-imager.

Comment: What I could break? Do you mean I broke something in hardware ?

Comment: No, you said `I tried to run "rpiboot -d recovery" with a modified bootloader` ... what did you modify?

Comment: I added 6 to boot order and enabled BOOT_UART=1. After that I tried to put initial values and flash it back but it didn't help anymore.

Comment: that's odd ... because `BOOT_ORDER=0xf25641` is how `usbboot` comes out of the box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132378/discussion-between-hanni76-and-bravo).

Comment: `I have tried SD card` and the CM4 didn't boot?

Comment: No, like I said , it simply ignores anything besides USB boot. It skips SD card boot.

Comment: So, if you have just an SD card correctly imaged, the CM4 doesn't boot at all?

Comment: Exactly so, as if SD card was not there or J2(1-2) fitted.

Comment: I said it's *how usbboot comes out of the box* - sorry, I use current master version - not sure what the "release" version does - perhaps you should use the latest git version instead (i.e. git clone the repo)

Comment: I am using usbboot git source from the beginning.

Comment: no you aren't, because if you were you would not need to add the `6` to the boot order